# Use Google Drive API without user's private information

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to a user's Drive. I have an Android application backed by a web server, so I can either upload the file directly from the device or have my backend do it.

**I don't want access to identifiable information.** Privacy is important for my users, and I don't want them to consent to giving me their profile. I don't need it and won't use it.

How can I remove the user's profile from the scope of my token?

[image]

In Android code, for my `GoogleSignInOptions` I'm deliberately NOT using the default scopes, which include profile info. This was my attempt when trying to use my backend:

```
val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder()
        .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE)) // only my own app's files
        .requestIdToken("<my app id>")
        .build()
```

Removing the `requestIdToken` without including `requestEmail` causes the flow to fail, because no token or ID is returned at all.

Comment: Why do you want to remove `requestIdToken`?

Comment: With that, when the consensus dialog pops up, it says something like "This app wants to associate you with your Google information" (in addition to the Drive permission), which for some of my users will sound like espionage